# Expected primary expression before

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I have the following code in a translator.h file

```
class Dictionary
{

 public:
  Dictionary(const char dictFileName[]);
  void translate(char out_s[], const char s[]);
```

and I call the function in my translator.cpp file as follows

```
for (int i=0; i<2000;i++) 
{
Dictionary:: translate (out_s[],temp_eng_words[i]); 
}
```

Which gives me an error "expected primary expression before ']' token". I don't understand what is wrong, and decided against putting up the whole code if the problem can be found in the above snippet.

Any ideas??

I already tried it without the [] for out_s, but it gives me an error "cannot call member function void dictionary::translate (char*, const char *)  without object". I'll post the whole code to give a clearer indication of what the problem might be.

```
Translator.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Translator.h"

using namespace std;

void Dictionary::translate(char out_s[], const char s[])
{
int i;
char englishWord[MAX_NUM_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN];

for (i=0;i < numEntries; i++)
{
if (strcmp(englishWord[i], s)==0)
break;
}

if (i<numEntries)
strcpy(out_s,elvishWord[i]);
}

char Translator::toElvish(const char elvish_line[],const char english_line[])

{
int j=0;
int k=0;
char temp_eng_words[2000][50];
char out_s;
//char temp_elv_words[2000][50]; NOT SURE IF I NEED THIS

std::string str = english_line;
std::  istringstream stm(str);
string word;
while( stm >> word) // read white-space delimited tokens one by one
{

strcpy (temp_eng_words[k],word.c_str());

k++;

}

for (int i=0; i<2000;i++)
{
Dictionary:: translate (out_s,temp_eng_words[i]); // ERROR RELATES TO THIS LINE -     cannot call member function like this.    error -  expected primary expression
// before ] if written out_s[].

}
}



Translator::Translator(const char dictFileName[]) : dict(dictFileName)
{
char englishWord[2000][50];
char temp_eng_word[50];
char temp_elv_word[50];
char elvishWord[2000][50];
int num_entries;

fstream str;

str.open(dictFileName, ios::in);
int i;

while (!str.fail())
{
for (i=0; i< 2000; i++)
{
str>> temp_eng_word;
str>> temp_elv_word;
strcpy(englishWord[i],temp_eng_word);
strcpy(elvishWord[i],temp_elv_word);
 }

num_entries = i;

}

 str.close();

}
}
```

translator.h

```
const int MAX_NUM_WORDS=2000;
const int MAX_WORD_LEN=50;

class Dictionary
{

public:
Dictionary(const char dictFileName[]);
void translate(char out_s[], const char s[]); // s represents a wor out_s, the    translated word

private:

char englishWord[MAX_NUM_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN];
char elvishWord[MAX_NUM_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN];
int numEntries;
};

class Translator
{
public:
 Translator(const char s[]);
 char toElvish(const char out_s[],const char s[]);
 char toEnglish(char out_s[], const char s[]);

 private:
  Dictionary dict;

};
```

Comment: Regarding your second error: `translate` is a non-static member of `Dictionary`. You must call it on an object, an instance of `Dictionary`. There seems to be one in the `Translator` class, so you probably meant `dict.translate(out_s, temp_eng_words[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is passing `out_s[]`, try this one:

```
Dictionary::translate (out_s,temp_eng_words[i]);
```

if `out_s` is an array then passing it without `[]` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler expects an array index in your actual parameter `out_s[]`.

What do you mean by `out_s[]`? If `out_s` is an array of `char` or a pointer to `char`, then pass `out_s` (without brackets).

Answer (score 1):

First note that a function signature like `void translate(char out_s[], const char s[])` is actually equivalent to `void translate(char* out_s, const char* s)`.

One of the arguments you're trying to pass is `out_s[]` - this isn't valid. You either need to pass the array itself `out_s` (which will undergo array-to-pointer conversion) or a specific element of it `out_s[i]`.

From where I'm standing, it seems that you want to pass `out_s`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for (int i=0; i<2000;i++) 
{
  Dictionary:: translate (out_s,temp_eng_words[i]); 
}
```